# How common/acceptable is it to omit "le sang" from "avoir de quoi glacer"?

Tags: expressions

> Cette coutume **a de quoi glacer**.

To express the idea of "ça me fait froid dans le dos" or "ça me donne des sueurs froides", I usually say the sentence above with the additional "le sang" at the end.

But I wonder if you could just as well do without the "le sang" without causing  ambiguity?

Answer (score 3):

French people will understand this sentence if the context is well established, and **if it is obvious that we speak of fear**. But it's *not natural* and no one says that without completing the phrase "Cette coutume me glace le sang", "Cette coutume à de quoi glacer le sang".

Answer (score 1):

As @Doubidou said, it will be understood in a well defined context, but I have never heard it and would not say it.

If you really want to avoid saying "le sang", then you can use "glaçant", as in :

> Le récit est glaçant

A quick research on Google with *glaçant* only points out to murder stories and such, so the context is quite clear on its own.